# Reading WiFi Data usage in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, cellular-network, wifi

Can any one give me an idea on how to read WiFi/cellular data usage of other applications to our application in iOS?

Comment: you have only access to your own application's sandbox, I believe what you want is not possible on a non-jailbroken iOS device.

Comment: Yeah Thanks @KaanDedeogl , but if I want to read data usage within my device what I need to do, and with jailbroken device .